# Reanimate Data Values in CharJS

Tags: javascript, chart.js

i have a small situation here.

I have 2 charts in same page, every time that user clicked in first chart, the second one alter the data property... the first time i click everything works fine, but if i click in another segment of first chart and back to the previous segment clicked before, the animation of my chart simply don't work and the data appears 
immediately without any animation.

I already try reset(). but simply don't work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/main.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.7.0/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <section id="banner_topo">
       <p>Cronograma</p> 
    </section>
     <div id="graficos">
        <div class="graficoAnual" style="float: left; left: 0px; width: 800px; margin-top: 10px;"> 
            <canvas id="myChartAno"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div id="graficoMensal">
            <p id="mes">Valores Mensais</p>
              <canvas id="myChartMes" class="chartjs-render-monitor"></canvas>
        </div>
      </div>        
  
 
    <script>

        var dataAno = {
          datasets: [{
            data: [300, 150, 100,500,323,145,665,143,211,100,123,400],
            backgroundColor: [
              "#F7464A",
              "#46BFBD",
              "#FDB45C",
              "#9400D3",
              "#4169E1",
              "#CD5C5C",
              "#FF6347",
              "#20B2AA",
              "#3CB371",
              "#FF8C00",
              "#DAA520",
              "#B0E0E6"
            ]
          }],
          labels: [
            "Janeiro",
            "Feveireiro",
            "Março",
            "Abril",
            "Maio",
            "Junho",
            "Julho",
            "Agosto",
            "Setembro",
            "Outubro",
            "Novembro",
            "Dezembro"
            ]
};

    var canvasAno = document.getElementById("myChartAno");
    var ctxAno = canvasAno.getContext("2d");
    var myNewChartAno = new Chart(ctxAno, {
      type: 'doughnut',
      data: dataAno,
      options: {
        legend: {
          position: 'bottom',
          fullWidth: true
        },
        animation: {
          duration: 4000
          }
        }  
      
    });


var dataLimpa = {
  datasets: [{
    data: [0, 0, 0],
    backgroundColor: [
      "#F7464A",
      "#46BFBD",
      "#FDB45C"
    ]
  }],
  labels: [
    "Red",
    "Green",
    "Yellow"
  ],
};

var dataJan = {
  datasets: [{
    data: [30, 50, 100],
    backgroundColor: [
      "#F7464A",
      "#46BFBD",
      "#FDB45C"
    ]
  }],
  labels: [
    "Red",
    "Green",
    "Yellow"
  ],
};

    var dataFev = {
  datasets: [{
    data: [150, 50, 100],
    backgroundColor: [
      "#F7464A",
      "#46BFBD",
      "#FDB45C"
    ]
  }],
  labels: [
    "Red",
    "Green",
    "Yellow"
  ]
};

    var dataMar = {
  datasets: [{
    data: [5, 50, 100],
    backgroundColor: [
      "#F7464A",
      "#46BFBD",
      "#FDB45C"
    ]
  }],
  labels: [
    "Red",
    "Green",
    "Yellow"
  ]
};

    var dataAbr = {
  datasets: [{
    data: [32, 50, 100],
    backgroundColor: [
      "#F7464A",
      "#46BFBD",
      "#FDB45C"
    ]
  }],
  labels: [
    "Red",
    "Green",
    "Yellow"
  ]
};

    var dataMai = {
  datasets: [{
    data: [654, 50, 100],
    backgroundColor: [
      "#F7464A",
      "#46BFBD",
      "#FDB45C"
    ]
  }],
  labels: [
    "Red",
    "Green",
    "Yellow"
  ]
};

    var dataJun = {
  datasets: [{
    data: [53, 50, 100],
    backgroundColor: [
      "#F7464A",
      "#46BFBD",
      "#FDB45C"
    ]
  }],
  labels: [
    "Red",
    "Green",
    "Yellow"
  ]
};

    var dataJul = {
  datasets: [{
    data: [21, 50, 100],
    backgroundColor: [
      "#F7464A",
      "#46BFBD",
      "#FDB45C"
    ]
  }],
  labels: [
    "Red",
    "Green",
    "Yellow"
  ]
};

    var dataAgo = {
  datasets: [{
    data: [423, 50, 100],
    backgroundColor: [
      "#F7464A",
      "#46BFBD",
      "#FDB45C"
    ]
  }],
  labels: [
    "Red",
    "Green",
    "Yellow"
  ]
};

    var dataSet = {
  datasets: [{
    data: [1300, 50, 100],
    backgroundColor: [
      "#F7464A",
      "#46BFBD",
      "#FDB45C"
    ]
  }],
  labels: [
    "Red",
    "Green",
    "Yellow"
  ]
};

    var dataOut = {
  datasets: [{
    data: [213, 50, 100],
    backgroundColor: [
      "#F7464A",
      "#46BFBD",
      "#FDB45C"
    ]
  }],
  labels: [
    "Red",
    "Green",
    "Yellow"
  ]
};

  var dataNov = {
  datasets: [{
    data: [765, 50, 100],
    backgroundColor: [
      "#F7464A",
      "#46BFBD",
      "#FDB45C"
    ]
  }],
  labels: [
    "Red",
    "Green",
    "Yellow"
  ]
};

    var dataDez = {
  datasets: [{
    data: [3100, 50, 100],
    backgroundColor: [
      "#F7464A",
      "#46BFBD",
      "#FDB45C"
    ]
  }],
  labels: [
    "Red",
    "Green",
    "Yellow"
  ]
};
  
    var canvasMes = document.getElementById("myChartMes");
    var ctxMes = canvasMes.getContext("2d");
    var myNewChartMes = new Chart(ctxMes, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: dataDez,
      options:{
        responsive: true,
        scales: {
      xAxes: [{
       stacked: true,
      }],
      yAxes: [{
       stacked: true
      }]
     },
      }
    });
  

        
     canvasAno.onclick = function(evt){
            var activePoints = myNewChartAno.getElementsAtEvent(evt);
            if (activePoints[0]) {
            var chartData = activePoints[0]['_chart'].config.data;
            var idx = activePoints[0]['_index'];
            var mesclicado; 
            var dataSelect; 
        
            switch (idx){
              case 0:
                mesclicado = 'Janeiro';
                dataSelect = dataJan;
                break;
              case 1:
                mesclicado = 'Fevereiro';
                dataSelect = dataFev;
                break;
              case 2:
                mesclicado = 'Março';
                dataSelect = dataMar;
                break;
              case 3:
                mesclicado = 'Abril';
                dataSelect = dataAbr;
                break;
              case 4:
                mesclicado = 'Maio';
                dataSelect = dataMai;
                break;
              case 5:
                mesclicado = 'Junho';
                dataSelect = dataJun;
                break;
              case 6:
                mesclicado = 'Julho';
                dataSelect = dataJul;
                break;
              case 7:
                mesclicado = 'Agosto';
                dataSelect = dataAgo;
                break;
              case 8:
                mesclicado = 'Setembro';
                dataSelect = dataSet;
                break;
              case 9:
                mesclicado = 'Outubro';
                dataSelect = dataOut;
                break;  
              case 10:
                mesclicado = 'Novembro';
                dataSelect = dataNov;
                break;  
              case 11:
                mesclicado = 'Dezembro';
                dataSelect = dataDez;
                break;  
            }
                document.getElementById('mes').innerHTML = mesclicado;
                myNewChartMes.data = dataSelect;                
                myNewChartMes.update();
                myNewChartMes.render({
             duration: 800,
              lazy: false,
              
            });
            
                
                
                
            }          
          }
        
                 
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Can someone Help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also come across the same problem where the animation only works only for the first time for a unique update, however, couldn't find the root cause.

But there is a nice and easy way to get this done is render a new chart after destroying the previous chart. I have used jQuery to clone the config to create a new chart in the below code, but you can use pure javascript also. See the below code or this working fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/jpzg7w2k/1/

```
var dataAno = {
  datasets: [{
    data: [300, 150, 100, 500, 323, 145, 665, 143, 211, 100, 123, 400],
    backgroundColor: [
      "#F7464A",
      "#46BFBD",
      "#FDB45C",
      "#9400D3",
      "#4169E1",
      "#CD5C5C",
      "#FF6347",
      "#20B2AA",
      "#3CB371",
      "#FF8C00",
      "#DAA520",
      "#B0E0E6"
    ]
  }],
  labels: [
    "Janeiro",
    "Feveireiro",
    "Março",
    "Abril",
    "Maio",
    "Junho",
    "Julho",
    "Agosto",
    "Setembro",
    "Outubro",
    "Novembro",
    "Dezembro"
  ]
};

var canvasAno = document.getElementById("myChartAno");
var ctxAno = canvasAno.getContext("2d");
var myNewChartAno = new Chart(ctxAno, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: dataAno,
  options: {
    legend: {
      position: 'bottom',
      fullWidth: true
    },
    animation: {
      duration: 4000
    }
  }
});


var dataLimpa = {
  datasets: [{
    data: [0, 0, 0],
    backgroundColor: [
      "#F7464A",
      "#46BFBD",
      "#FDB45C"
    ]
  }],
  labels: [
    "Red",
    "Green",
    "Yellow"
  ],
};

var dataJan = {
  datasets: [{
    data: [30, 50, 100],
    backgroundColor: [
      "#F7464A",
      "#46BFBD",
      "#FDB45C"
    ]
  }],
  labels: [
    "Red",
    "Green",
    "Yellow"
  ],
};

var dataFev = {
  datasets: [{
    data: [150, 50, 100],
    backgroundColor: [
      "#F7464A",
      "#46BFBD",
      "#FDB45C"
    ]
  }],
  labels: [
    "Red",
    "Green",
    "Yellow"
  ]
};

var dataMar = {
  datasets: [{
    data: [5, 50, 100],
    backgroundColor: [
      "#F7464A",
      "#46BFBD",
      "#FDB45C"
    ]
  }],
  labels: [
    "Red",
    "Green",
    "Yellow"
  ]
};

var dataAbr = {
  datasets: [{
    data: [32, 50, 100],
    backgroundColor: [
      "#F7464A",
      "#46BFBD",
      "#FDB45C"
    ]
  }],
  labels: [
    "Red",
    "Green",
    "Yellow"
  ]
};

var dataMai = {
  datasets: [{
    data: [654, 50, 100],
    backgroundColor: [
      "#F7464A",
      "#46BFBD",
      "#FDB45C"
    ]
  }],
  labels: [
    "Red",
    "Green",
    "Yellow"
  ]
};

var dataJun = {
  datasets: [{
    data: [53, 50, 100],
    backgroundColor: [
      "#F7464A",
      "#46BFBD",
      "#FDB45C"
    ]
  }],
  labels: [
    "Red",
    "Green",
    "Yellow"
  ]
};

var dataJul = {
  datasets: [{
    data: [21, 50, 100],
    backgroundColor: [
      "#F7464A",
      "#46BFBD",
      "#FDB45C"
    ]
  }],
  labels: [
    "Red",
    "Green",
    "Yellow"
  ]
};

var dataAgo = {
  datasets: [{
    data: [423, 50, 100],
    backgroundColor: [
      "#F7464A",
      "#46BFBD",
      "#FDB45C"
    ]
  }],
  labels: [
    "Red",
    "Green",
    "Yellow"
  ]
};

var dataSet = {
  datasets: [{
    data: [1300, 50, 100],
    backgroundColor: [
      "#F7464A",
      "#46BFBD",
      "#FDB45C"
    ]
  }],
  labels: [
    "Red",
    "Green",
    "Yellow"
  ]
};

var dataOut = {
  datasets: [{
    data: [213, 50, 100],
    backgroundColor: [
      "#F7464A",
      "#46BFBD",
      "#FDB45C"
    ]
  }],
  labels: [
    "Red",
    "Green",
    "Yellow"
  ]
};

var dataNov = {
  datasets: [{
    data: [765, 50, 100],
    backgroundColor: [
      "#F7464A",
      "#46BFBD",
      "#FDB45C"
    ]
  }],
  labels: [
    "Red",
    "Green",
    "Yellow"
  ]
};

var dataDez = {
  datasets: [{
    data: [3100, 50, 100],
    backgroundColor: [
      "#F7464A",
      "#46BFBD",
      "#FDB45C"
    ]
  }],
  labels: [
    "Red",
    "Green",
    "Yellow"
  ]
};

var canvasMes = document.getElementById("myChartMes");
var ctxMes = canvasMes.getContext("2d");

var myNewChartMes = new Chart(ctxMes, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: dataDez,
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true
      }]
    },
  }
});



canvasAno.onclick = function(evt) {
  var activePoints = myNewChartAno.getElementsAtEvent(evt);
  if (activePoints[0]) {
    var chartData = activePoints[0]['_chart'].config.data;
    var idx = activePoints[0]['_index'];
    var mesclicado;
    var dataSelect;

    switch (idx) {
      case 0:
        mesclicado = 'Janeiro';
        dataSelect = dataJan;
        break;
      case 1:
        mesclicado = 'Fevereiro';
        dataSelect = dataFev;
        break;
      case 2:
        mesclicado = 'Março';
        dataSelect = dataMar;
        break;
      case 3:
        mesclicado = 'Abril';
        dataSelect = dataAbr;
        break;
      case 4:
        mesclicado = 'Maio';
        dataSelect = dataMai;
        break;
      case 5:
        mesclicado = 'Junho';
        dataSelect = dataJun;
        break;
      case 6:
        mesclicado = 'Julho';
        dataSelect = dataJul;
        break;
      case 7:
        mesclicado = 'Agosto';
        dataSelect = dataAgo;
        break;
      case 8:
        mesclicado = 'Setembro';
        dataSelect = dataSet;
        break;
      case 9:
        mesclicado = 'Outubro';
        dataSelect = dataOut;
        break;
      case 10:
        mesclicado = 'Novembro';
        dataSelect = dataNov;
        break;
      case 11:
        mesclicado = 'Dezembro';
        dataSelect = dataDez;
        break;
    }

    document.getElementById('mes').innerHTML = mesclicado;

    var config = $.extend(true, {}, myNewChartMes.config);
    var canvasMes = document.getElementById("myChartMes");
    var ctxMes = canvasMes.getContext("2d");    

    config.data = dataSelect; 

    if(myNewChartMes)
    {
        myNewChartMes.destroy();
    }

    myNewChartMes = new Chart(ctxMes, config);                             
  }
}
```